# ASP.NET Core Web API - Unable to resolve service for type 'IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Services.CurrentUserService'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing CurrentUser Service in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API User Authentication Login. I am using IdentityDbContext:

ICurrentUserService:

```cs
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }
    bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    public string IpAddress { get; }
}
```

CurrentUserService:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    public string IpAddress { get; }

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        IpAddress = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        UserName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        IsAuthenticated = UserId != null;
    }
}
```

Then in the Program.cs I have this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Register CurrentUserService
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

But while I tried to run the Application, I get this error:

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Services.ICurrentUserService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Services.CurrentUserService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Services.CurrentUserService'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\MyApp\WebApi\Program.cs:line 15

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Services.ICurrentUserService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Services.CurrentUserService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Services.CurrentUserService'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Services.CurrentUserService'.
```

```cs
var app = builder.Build()
```

is line 15

How do I get this resolved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register `HttpContextAccessor` dependency.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

// Register CurrentUserService
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

---

**References**

[Use HttpContext from custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)